# How can I remove this stuck bathtub drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I need to remove my tubs drain and am having trouble. The tub drain wrench from home Depot is slightly too large to fit. Thus I've tried locking pliers to no avail. I've tried boiling water to loosen up anything if need be. I'm wondering if it's somehow attached to the pipes and doesn't screw before I keep trying too hard and go buy one of those inserts that will damage the pipe inside. Can anyone tell from the pictures? Thank you for any help!!!

[image]

Comment: Maybe try jamming needlenose pliers into opposing quadrants, and rotating the pliers whatever way you can.  Depending how much is stuck above the flange you might be able to use vise grips.  If the tub is steel or cast iron, you might also try torching the barrel of the drain to break up the corrosion some.

Comment: Or this? [How to remove old drain strainer from a bathtub?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/231303/35141)

Answer (score 0):

That drain fitting is designed to be screwed into the pipe below and the only way to remove it without cutting it out with a rotary tool and cutoff wheel is to unscrew it. If possible, try grinding down the drain wrench you have to make it fit. You can also shove a litle plumbers putty down there to get the exact shape and hunt around to some plumbing stores to get the right size drain wrench. I've had luck using needlenosed pliers and turning the pliers with an adjustable wrench.

Comment: I got a tub drain wrench at Lowes and it falls into the drain but the teeth are slightly too big. The one from home depot would likely have the same issue! I'll try sanding the teeth on the one from Lowe's. I've tried pliers and a pipe wrench to no avail. It seems super stuck, with the pliers I gave it all my strength and the pliers grip loses and they fly off the drain. Even with locking pliers. I've tried adjusting and tightening as much as possible but still. I'm surprised it didn't break the "x" like in other stories. But this seems super sturdy compared to a new drain I just bought. Hmm!